# ASP.NET cache - guaranteed expiration time

Tags: asp.net, caching

If I put a cache item to ASP.NET cache and set the expiration time, e.g. 1 hour, is it possible that it will disappear from cache before it has expired?

I guess it might happen if cache does not have enough memory.

Thanks

Maxim

Comment: It also happens if the application pool is recycled.

Comment: Checkout this: [CacheItemPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitempriority.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every cache-engine implementations has its own eviction policies. Data are often evicted because there might be a risk of running out of memory. Cache might choose to evict Least Recently Used (LRE), or Least Frequently Used with Dynamic Aging (LFDA), depending on its settings.

In order to avoid eviction issues, check your cache memory usage and limits, and set eviction configuration options accordingly.